# Maven can't find artifacts

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, pom.xml

After I'd searched the net and similar StackOverflow questions and tried to apply the proposed sollutions I didn't come up with an idea how to fix this error, which gives me pom.xml:

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
- Missing artifact jakarta.json:jakarta.json-
 api:jar:2.0.0-RC3
- Missing artifact org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-
 locator:jar:3.0.0-M2
- Missing artifact org.glassfish:jakarta.json:jar:2.0.0-
 RC3
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 //error appears here 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.gson</groupId>
<artifactId>advanced-jaxrs-01</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>advanced-jaxrs-01 Maven Webapp</name>
<!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
<url>http://www.example.com</url>

<properties>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
  <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<dependencies>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.media/jersey-
media-moxy -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-M6</version>
</dependency>
<!-- 
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.bundles/jaxrs-ri - 
->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.bundles</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxrs-ri</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-M6</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
  <finalName>advanced-jaxrs-01</finalName>
  <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven 
   defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
    </plugin>
    <!-- see http://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default- 
bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_war_packaging -->
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.2</version>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.0</version>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.22.1</version>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.2</version>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.5.2</version>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.8.2</version>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

I've had a look at .m2/repository and I've noticed, that there are files maven can't find. What should I do? What's the matter?

Comment: Look at [the central repository](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/jakarta/json/jakarta.json-api/). There is no RC3 version of jakarta.json-api and jakarta-json

Comment: And the newest version of hk2-locator is 2.6.1

Comment: How can appear such thing when I don't try to download these jars explicitly?...

Comment: Why do you use org.json as the group id of your project?

Comment: Not j.son, but g.son)

Comment: Yes, but why did you use it as the group id of your project? That should be the reverse nsme of a domain you own.

Comment: Why not?) Moreover, I have no my own domain... Is it forbidden to name groupId in such way?

Comment: It eon't be a problem until you publish it. Anyway, I think your provlem is that your dependencies reference those dependencieswith wrong versions.

Comment: What should I do?

Comment: Maybe try to add the eclipselink repository: `<repositories>

<repository>

<id>eclipselink.repository</id>

<name>Eclipse Maven Repository</name>

<url>https://download.eclipse.org/rt/eclipselink/maven.repo</url>

<layout>default</layout>

</repository>

</repositories>`

Comment: I've done it, nothing changes...

Answer (score 0):

If there are files that maven can't find, you can always try to install the JAR file and going into

Project folder properties --> Java Build Path --> Add external JARs (Click on Modulepath if you cant immediately press Add External JARs)

Comment: There are no such versions of needed jars in central repo, but maven somehow demands them